# how to style antd tabs component?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

The below UI is of antd tabs. I need to expand the tab item but for some reason it doesn't work as expected.

Current UI:
[image]

Desired UI:
[image]

**Code:**

```
const App = () => (
  <Tabs
    defaultActiveKey="1"
    onChange={onChange}
    style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
  >
    <TabPane tab="Details" key="1" style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      Content of Tab Pane 1
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Updates" key="2">
      Content of Tab Pane 2
    </TabPane>
  </Tabs>
);
```

Even though I have given `justify-content:space-between` or custom `width` it doesn't change.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-22-4-forked-hxise4?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs you should use **tabBarStyle** instead of **style**. You can read more here: https://ant.design/components/tabs/

**EDIT:**

[image]

by applying **tabBarStyle** the CSS properties are appended to the upper div (the red container). In order to work it should be applied to the bottom div (the blue container):

[image]

You can try custom styling via CSS

**EDIT #2:**

This worked fine for me:

```
.ant-tabs-nav-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.ant-tabs-tab {
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Tried with tabBarStyle also

Comment: Tried custom css, width works but the blue line nor the text expands as expected